# Retrieve all checkbox checked in the table when submitting form

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html-table, submit

I have a `<table>` in my form that contains some rows retrieved from database  and on each row I put a checkbox, and

the name of the checkbox tag is the id of the row record

and the value changes according to the state of checkbox 1 : checked, 0:unchecked

I want to send the selected rows id when user submit the form : 
I don't know how can I achieve that :

```
 <table border=1 id="mondiv" class="hidden" >
            <th></th>
            <th>Numero</th>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prenom</th>
            <th>Spécialité</th>
{% for item in users %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.id }}" onchange="changeetat(this)" /></td>
                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.specialty }}</td>
            </tr>
{% else %}
            <h2>Aucun organisateur trouvé</h2>
 {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

and here is the Javascript method:

```
    function changeetat(element){
    if(element.checked){
       element.value = '1';
   }
   else{
       element.value = '0';
   }

}
```

I use twig template with Symfony

Answer (score 1):

if you're not using jQuery than :

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or
document.forms[0].elements;  
var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes  
var checked = []; //will contain all checked checkboxes  
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {  
    if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
        cbs.push(inputs[i]);  
        if (inputs[i].checked) {  
            checked.push(inputs[i]);  
        }  
    }  
}  
var nbCbs = cbs.length; //number of checkboxes  
var nbChecked = checked.length; //number of checked checkboxes
```

with jQuery:

```
var cbs = $("input:checkbox:checked");
```

Comment: @karthik you didn't improve clarity, you ruined the code formatting. Please don't edit if you don't know how to format, thanks.